# How did they obtain $15-15i$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products

This might be a silly question, but how did they get $15-15i$ for example 1? The operation they did didn't follow any of the definitions listed (a-d). Did they use operation a? If so, where did they get $z$ from because the question only gave $x$ & $y$ within $C^2$, and why did they use the conjugate of $y$?[image]

Lastly, why does $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y.x\rangle$ in definition c.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the product and using $i^2=-1$,

$$(1+i)(2+3i)+4(4-5i)=2+3i+2i+3i^2+16-20i$$

$$=2+5i-3+16-20i=15-15i.$$

Comment: ahh okay. But, why did you use the conjugate rather than the given values?

Comment: No, I just expanded the product out like $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$ and used the fact that $i^2=-1$. I didn't used any conjugation